# Kotlin: Is there any way to get the background color from a button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to compare the color between a button and a text but I can not find the way.

I tried printing myBtn.background and myText.textColor but its not showing what im looking

```
println("btn-> " + btn.background + " | text -> " + text.textColor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button background is instance of Drawable, while textColor is Int. That is why you cannot compare this values. In order to get Int value of color of drawable object use `(btn.background as ColorDrawable).color`
and compare it to `text.textColor`